# Document Viewer installation in Plone

Tags: plone, openoffice.org, libreoffice

I have been trying to install document.viewer on Plone that would allow me to view pdf documents inline, so far i am able to convert pdf files and view them, but when i try to convert .doc .ppt files it gives the following error, My operating system is Fedora.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/collective.documentviewer-2.2-py2.7.egg/collective/documentviewer/convert.py", line 530, in __call__
    pages = self.run_conversion()
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/collective.documentviewer-2.2-py2.7.egg/collective/documentviewer/convert.py", line 379, in run_conversion
    return docsplit.convert(self.storage_dir, **args)
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/collective.documentviewer-2.2-py2.7.egg/collective/documentviewer/convert.py", line 285, in convert
    self.convert_to_pdf(path, filename, output_dir)
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/collective.documentviewer-2.2-py2.7.egg/collective/documentviewer/convert.py", line 256, in convert_to_pdf
    self._run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/collective.documentviewer-2.2-py2.7.egg/collective/documentviewer/convert.py", line 118, in _run_command
    raise Exception(error)
Exception: Command
/usr/local/bin/docsplit pdf /tmp/tmp9c0S1q/dump.doc --output /tmp/tmp9c0S1q
finished with return code
1
and output:
Error: Could not find or load main class .usr.lib.libreoffice
```

Note that i have already installed openoffice and there is a folder named libreoffice in the usr/lib folder. Plone is installed as a standalone with administrative rights. How can i solve this issue?

Comment: try the command in the log manually and see what might be going wrong with docsplit.

Comment: Take a look at this issue: https://github.com/collective/collective.documentviewer/issues/11 hopefully that'll help you resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Did you install all dependencies as in https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.documentviewer/#install-requirements ?

Comment: Yes i have installed all dependencies